# How to correctly handle `SQLExecDirectW` and `SQLEndTran` (Error 0x20) using SQLAlchemy and pyodbc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm programming a multi-threaded application using 10 threads that each creates a session at the beginning of a loop and destroys it at the end:

```
try:
    ss = Session()
    ...
    ss.add_all(object_matches) # list of objects to add to the database
    ss.commit()
finally:
    ss.close()
```

My problem is the errors `SQLEndTran` and `SQLExecDirectW` (see below) that occurs seemingly randomly against my MSSQL server. I've read the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#error-e3q8) for a description of the corresponding error code (`0x20`), but creating the engine with `pool_pre_ping=True` doesn't resolve the issue:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sa:P@ssw0rd@localhost:1433/watchdog?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", pool_size=20, max_overflow=10, pool_pre_ping=True, echo=False)
```

Neither does settings `autocommit=True`: `ss = Session(autocommit=True)`

As a possible solution, I `commit()` repeatably in a loop and only cast the exception, if it occurs three times:

```
for i in range(3):
    try:
        ss.add_all(object_matches)
        ss.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        if i == 2: raise e
    else:
        break
```

Is this the proper way to deal with these errors, or how should I approach them?

Note: I'm running MSSQL using the Docker image: `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`.

**SQLEndTran**:

```
ERROR -- 04/09/2020 09:43:04 AM -- sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool -- ThreadPoolExecutor-0_6  -- Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 733, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 538, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x20 (32) (SQLEndTran)')
```

**SQLExecDirectW**:

```
ERROR -- 04/09/2020 09:43:55 AM -- root -- ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2  -- (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x20 (32) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO objects (id, version, type, rest_url, space_id, title, created_by, created_time, modified_by, modified_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (('335810454', 1, 'attachment', 'https://confluence.danskenet.net/rest/api/content/335810454', 36831243, 'DPO Article 32 Assessment Digital Signing.pdf', 'BD7863', datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7, 16, 14, 26, 727000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200))), 'BD7863', datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7, 16, 14, 26, 727000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))), ('254106314', 23, 'page', 'https://confluence.danskenet.net/rest/api/content/254106314', 36831243, 'Cloud 2 Front End Assessment 2019-2020', 'BD7863', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 9, 48, 40, 323000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600))), 'BD7863', datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7, 16, 15, 14, 907000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1228, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/pyodbc.py", line 413, in do_executemany
    cursor, statement, parameters, context=context
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 585, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x20 (32) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```